# Dynamic vs static module name call? In terms of performance

Tags: performance, elixir, metaprogramming

I have something like this:

```
      my_var = get_my_var()
      res =
        case my_var do
          :var1 ->
            MyApp.M1.Var1.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)

          :var2 ->
            MyApp.M1.Var2.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)

          :var3 ->
            MyApp.M1.Var3.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)

          _ ->
            Logger.error("unknown")
        end
```

In terms of performance, is this approach better than these:

```
      my_var = get_my_var()

      # 1
      my_mod = Module.safe_concat(MyApp.M1, my_var)
      res = my_mod.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)

      # 2
      my_mod = String.to_atom("Elixir.MyApp.M1.#{my_var}")
      res = my_mod.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

In other words, does **calling a method of a module** via a dynamically generated module name impact performance in a noticeble way?

Comment: The dynamic code is not equivalent to the static one, in the first place. `Module.safe_concat/2` is not going to titleize the atom for you. There should not be any noticeable impact, but nothing would tell it better than benchmarks. Just use kinda [`benchee`](https://hexdocs.pm/benchee) and check it yourself.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Матюшкин-Алексюшкин, а ты сделаешь мне бэнчмааааааарк? А???